# What are the settings of Daubechies and Complex Gaussian are called?

Tags: wavelet

Hello What are the numbers of Daubechies and Complex Gaussian are called?
 I dont know what to call db4 or cgau8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Daubechies wavelet, convention is **dbN**, where **N** is the number of [*vanishing moments*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128165/what-is-a-vanishing-moment).

In case of Complex Gaussian wavelet number describes derivative order:

$$\mathrm{cgau}(x)=C_n\left[e^{-ix}e^{-x^2}\right]^{(p)}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I can say:  (cgau4)>Complex Gaussian wavelet with 4th derivative order.  (db4)> daubechie wavelet with 4th vanishing moments. Right? @jojek

Comment: Indeed. I used to say *Complex Gaussian wavelet based on 4th order derivative*.

Comment: Thanks @jojek do you say: daubechie wavelet with 4th vanishing moments? or daubechie wavelet with 4th vanishing moments order, or what?

Comment: It's not 4th but 4. There is a four vanishing moments.